# Fractional part estimate

Tags: analysis

Apologies if this is a stupid question.

Let $\{s\} = s - [s]$ denote the fractional part of a real number $s$. Is there any $\alpha\in [0,1]$, such that there exist positive constants $c$ and $d$ with
$$\{k\alpha\} \geq \frac{c}{|k|^d} \quad \forall\; k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$$

I think there is actually a dense set of such $\alpha$'s, although I had a hard time finding any. Any idea?

Comment: Yes. In particular, "badly approximable" numbers exist. Also, look up "Liouville number" and some theorems he's proven.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!